# woocomerce products and categories don't display fixed

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a issues with wordpress the products and categories don t display someone help me and the file error.log placed in path /var/log/nginx

i was delete different file compressed with extension alternative.gz because already contact support to my hosting and any resolve someone can help me
the message error.log 
link here :https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_lDKj7h0SFZeDVyLXhoaTlGRVU/view?usp=sharing

[image: see the picture issues]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update permalinks, check the visibility of your products (can't be hidden) and make sure the products are published.

If none of these works, try deactivate your plugins one by one (checking your site after deactivate).

Comment: thanks for your answer my issues is solved server storage engine is full i have delete access.log in folder var/log/nginix and other project now it's perfect all